# How to prove this problem about field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Assume that $\alpha$ is algbraic over $F$,with $[F [\alpha] :F] =n$. If $\beta\in F[ \alpha ],$ show that $[F [\beta]:  F] \le n$.

We have Formula $$[E:F] = [E:K][K:F]$$ when $K$ is extension of $F$, $E$ is extension of $K$.

If we know $ F [\beta] $ is field, then this proposition is true. Let $m(X)$ be minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$; I want to prove $m(\beta) =0$, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why is there such a row by row?

Comment: Because you are using display math,. `$$`, instead of in-line, `$` And you misuse `\mathit`, and a generally did a rather poor job of using MathJax. Look at the edit to see how you should have done it.

Comment: Just take $E=F(\alpha)$ and $K=F(\beta)$ in the formula.

Comment: We frist should prove $F(\beta)$ is field?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How to look at the edit?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thinks,I known.

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks,i known since $F[\alpha]$ is  finite extension of $\mathit F$,so it is also algbraic extension of $F$.

Comment: I am a little confused right now. The notation $F[\beta]$ suggests you take the smallest **subring** containing $\beta$, while the degree is only defined (if I recall correctly) for a **field** extension... Are you sure you don’t want to take $F(\beta)$, which is the smallest **subfield** containing $\beta$ (and likewise $F(\alpha)$)?

Comment: since $F[\alpha]$ is algbraic extension of E(finite extension is algbraic extension).so $F(\beta)$ =$F[\beta]$.(def of algbraic extension)